# javascript on submit

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, onsubmit

i'm sorry i have a problem, when i submit input type submit in form html, why my function is not execute,
this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function submitHidden( ){
        document.getElementById("formParser").submit();
    }
    window.onload = setInterval(submitHidden, 10*1000 );

    function audioPlay(){
        document.getElementById("sirine").play();
        return true;
    }
</script>

<audio type="hidden" id="sirine" src="sirine.mp3" controls="controls">

<form id="formParser"  action="" method="post" onsubmit="audioPlay()">
<input type="submit" value="Click here to send">
</form>
```

why my audio sirine not play. any wrong with my code ?
im sory, i bad in english, thanks for advance, :)

Comment: You have to use `preventdefault()`

Comment: can you give me example, because im newbie in javascript :)

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for test your code, then we can review for you.

Comment: Now, you have your awnser and a jsfiddle demo, enjoy, will not work on IE < 9 try use jquery for better compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are submitting the form every 10 seconds in the `submitHidden()` function. When you use JavaScript's `submit()` function, it bypasses the `onSubmit` handler.

Comment: @insomniart Did you make the `audioPlay()` function `return false` ?

Comment: ok, i try with
`<script type="text/javascript">
   function submitHidden( ){
        document.getElementById("formParser").submit();
    }
    window.onload = setInterval(submitHidden, 10*1000 );

    function audioPlay(){
        document.getElementById("sirine").play();
        return true;
    }
</script>
<form id="formParser"  action="" method="post" onsubmit="audioPlay(); return false;">
<input type="submit" value="Click here to send">
</form>
`
but keep not work

Comment: @insomniart Try the code above and tell me if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try this `<form id="formParser"  action="" method="post" onsubmit="audioPlay(); return false;">` and it will work.

Comment: @AlexW, thanks for response again, but no work again,
my button submit is automatic submit with `window.onload = setInterval(submitHidden, 10*1000 );`

why ? where any wrong, because i play with button is ok, but with autosubmit cannot play

Comment: @GabrielGartz thanks for your response, but still doesn't work

Comment: @AlexW, ok i understand with my problem, because every `10*1000` auto submit, i change with `60*1000` keep doesnt work, any solution, when auto submit with `submitHidden` my audio can play

Comment: @insomniart Putting `audioPlay();` after `document.getElementById("formParser").submit();` in the `submitHidden()` function will achieve the result you are looking for.

Comment: @insomniart The thing to understand is, `document.getElementById("formParser").submit();` **bypasses** the `onSubmit` event handler function.

Comment: @AlexW ok, im sorry im miss understand before, :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's fix it for you.

First take a look in this fiddle that I've made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/gartz/7dASQ/3/

Let's explain:

1. if you use the method `submit()` it baypass the `onsubmit`
2. you can simulate the `click` event for the element button, that way will submit your form without bypassing onsubmit
3. Your audio element was with type wrong, the time is file tipe, not hidden, you can hide it using CSS `style="display: none"` or remove the `controls` tag

This is your fixed code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitHidden( ){
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    document.getElementById("submitButton").dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(submitHidden, 10*1000 );
  }

function audioPlay(){
    document.getElementById("sirine").play();
    return false;
}
</script>
<form id="formParser"  action="#" method="post" onsubmit="audioPlay(); return false;">
  <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Click here to send">
</form>
<audio id="sirine">
  <source src="http://musicsringtone.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/air-raid-siren-alert.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

PS.: I do not take responsibility if someone try to kill you because a sirene playing every 10 secconds.

Comment: excelent..... hahaha... i run when any one kill me, :p
thanxs @Gabriel , because i make sirine in GIS location of disaster victims. 

thanks alot... :D

Comment: you are welcome, good luck with you project, looks like will help people, I'm happy to can help you.